# Background Color for Positive Samples in Haar cascade training in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, colors, background, cascade

I noticed, that in OpenCV's opencv_createsamples utility for Haarcascade training you can specify a background color, which is black by default. Since I am now creating the positive samples I was wondering if it was beneficial to set all background pixels in the positive images to black, or if this would actually hurt the recognition / training process. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: Results are a lot better when the background is not entirely black. So using croped images without presegementation works well.

Answer (score 0):

The bgcolor parameter is 0 by default which does mean black but you can specify your own 8 bit color value. eg: To specify white, use `-bgcolor 255`

If you have the same background color in your positives and you supply the background images, then the positive will be overlaid on to the background images with the positives own background suitably turned transparent.

You can observe this in effect using the `-show` parameter

Comment: What do you do if your positive examples have all different background colors, or don't have a solid background color at all?